# C# .NET Core Console.ReadKey(true) doesn't (always) intercept the key on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, terminal, .net-core

I'm working on my first .NET Core apps and to try their cross-platform functionality I've set up an Ubuntu VM. After installing .NET I moved my files to the VM and launched the program. Basically everything works fine - with one exception.

When I use `Console.ReadKey(true);` I should get the pressed key but the console shouldn't show it. On Windows it works fine, the Key is pressed and nothing is shown. But on Ubuntu the console still shows the keys I press.

So, how can I prevent this?
It looks like the character shown increase with the complexity of my program, more time between the calls of `Console.ReadKey(true);` means more chars shown.

I hope you can help me, Nils.

Code:

```cs
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long lastrun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            while (!PressedESC())
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks >= (lastrun + (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 5)))
                {
                    lastrun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                    // Here could be some dataprocessing but its not needed here...
                    // The problem already occures with this code.
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool PressedESC()
        {
            return Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape;
        }
    }
}
```

-> Only a few rapidly typed chars are shown

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long lastrun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            while (!PressedESC())
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Ticks >= (lastrun + (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 5)))
                {
                    lastrun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                    // Here could be some dataprocessing but its not needed here...
                    // The problem already occures with this code.
                }
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        private static bool PressedESC()
        {
            return Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape;
        }
    }
}
```

-> Every char I type is displayed.

What I've tried:
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Desktop) (VM) Terminal
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Desktop) (VM) Gnome Terminal
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Server) (VM) Terminal
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Server) (VM) PuTTY (from Windows)
Result is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why not this instead?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) {}
    }
}
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

(Note that some characters may still be printed on the screen if you're mashing the keyboard while the application is initializing. It takes some time for the runtime to initialize and compile your code before input can be intercepted. Once the program is running, however, all inputs should be captured.)

Comment: Well I do more than just wait until the user presses the escape key. Its just the exit condition. Atm I have nothing where its important, I use it only to keep the console clear of randomly pressed keys. But your version will stop the program at your condition. Anything in the loop would wait until any key except escape is pressed (thats why I use ```Console.KeyAvailable()```). I have my code running every five seconds and I check every 50ms if the program should stop (escape pressed). I know that ```Console.KeyAvaliable()``` isnt the problem, on Windows it works fine.

Comment: But I dont know what the exact problem is on Ubuntu and how I could fix it. Ive tested it with your version (exept I used my PressedESC() method) abd it worked also fine for me but its not only waiting for escape so an empty loop isnt what I need.

Comment: Depending on what your other work is, you could start it in a background thread using `Task.Run(() => DoWork());` before the `while` loop.

Comment: I could use tasks and threads but I want it exactly how it is abd it cant be that the terminal shows the keys I press and the cmd not. Especially when I say "dont show this!" :) I just want to know whats wrong and how canbI prevent this :) have you tested my code and got similar results?

Comment: well I found the problem: the terminal displays everything I type while not actively blocking it. I tried it with ```Thread.Sleep(50000);``` and pressed some keys... All are shown although I never read anything from the buffer...